# How to structure Two User Model (One for Public and another for Admin) in rails application through Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have Rails application for Book shop (e-commerce). I have two user Model one for Admin and One for Customer. I want to show all user that admin can see through admin panel and also I want to see Customer show page. I have used devise for both type of user. I am facing problems because devise generate all sign up and sign in logic automatically then how can i redirect that to some where in my app view not in root.

Answer (score 1):

Manohar I think it's unnecessary to create 2 models. You could just generate the user model with Devise then just a migration the following way:

```
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, default: false
   end
end
```

Which basically will create a flag allowing you to do something like this:

```
if current_user.admin?

end
```

If the page could potentially not have a current_user set then:

```
if current_user.try(:admin?)

end
```

Now to access the controllers from Devise this is the link:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app/controllers/devise

To set modify or extend the functionality of the controllers just create a devise directory within controllers and place the needed controller files within from devise.

This is a code example of one my apps:

```
# registrations_controller.rb

class MyDevise::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController 

   def new
      super
   end

   def create
      super
   end

   def update
      super
   end
 end
```

I just created a folder named my_devise inside my controller's folder once you have the code above you can just add functionality to the methods as you wish.